# MulterError: Unexpected field when trying to upload pdf file with React and Express using Multer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch-api, multer

Express.js and React.js error when trying to upload a pdf file
MulterError: Unexpected field

This is my frontend request code:

```
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("title", titleRef.current.value);
      formData.append("description", descriptionRef.current.value);
      formData.append("author", authorRef.current.value);
      formData.append("genres", genresRef.current.value);
      formData.append("image", thumbnail);
      formData.append("pdf", file);
      formData.append("userId", auth.userId);
      const responseData = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:5000/.../upload-post",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            // "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token,
          },
          body: formData,
        }
      );
```

This is my multer function call inside of express.Router().post at .../upload-post

```
router.post(
  ".../upload-post",

  imgUpload.single("image"),
  pdfUpload.single("pdf"),

  [
    //some express-validator checks
  ],
  controller.uploadPdf,
  controller.uploadPost
);
```

And here is my multer function itself

```
const MIME_TYPE_MAP_PDF = {
  "application/pdf": "pdf",
};

const pdfUpload = multer({
  limits: 500000,
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, `.../storage/${uuid()}`);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP_PDF[file.mimetype];
      cb(null, uuidv4() + "." + ext);
    },
  }),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const isValid = !!MIME_TYPE_MAP_PDF[file.mimetype];
    let error = isValid ? null : new Error("Invalid mime type!");
    cb(error, isValid);
  },
});
```

If I commented out pdfUpload.single("pdf") the error does not occur, so clearly there is a problem with that function. Any help would be very much appreciated, since this is my first time working with multer. Thanks

Comment: Your `pdfUpload` filters are rejecting the image because of its mime type. I think you'll have to use a generic upload handler with `fields([{name:'pdf'},{name:'image'}])` (see https://github.com/expressjs/multer#fieldsfields) and perform the validation elsewhere

Comment: Actually, try passing `null` in the `fileFilter` callback instead of an `Error`. That may just reject the `image` file without crashing the whole chain. You may need a similar filter in `imgUpload` though to reject the PDF, otherwise you'll be double-handling files

Comment: @Phil my imgUpload function is a different function entirely, and that does not cause any problems for me. It's something to do with pdfUpload.single("pdf")